# Setting the same theme across desktop environments

Tags: themes, desktop-environments

I'm currently running 13.04 Gnome-Shell. It's customised just the way I like it. However, when I switch to Unity, the desktop looks really ugly - a real mess!

How can I set one DE to look the way I want it to, and when I switch to another DE it looks the same? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

all gnome-based DE use same theme on same account (gnome-shell unity, cinnamon, elementary, gnome classic). 
try to change your theme maby is not compatibile with unity.
if you use 13.04 look theme for gnome 3.6 is the best results